# USB bulkTransfer errors after sending nulls

Tags: android

I am using FTDI usb-serial dongle to send binary data from my android device,Asus transformer, to a industrial controller.
I am using code from http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=370&cpage=1 (thanks Manuel Di Cerbo ) 
It works fine as long as I do not send nulls, but after a null is sent the rest of the data is corrupted.

Questions.
Should it work? and/or
Can anyone confirm what I am seeing?

```
public byte[] dataframe = new byte[256];
......
......
    for(;;){//this is the main loop for transferring        
                conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, dataframe, 10, 0);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(mStop){
                    mStopped = true;
                    return;
                }
                l("sent "+dataframe[0]+","+dataframe[1]+","+dataframe[2]);

            }
        }
```

This thread resends the data periodically, currently 10 bytes but it will be more, while the main app updates some of the values. Normally most of the bytes would be zero, with some changing data. At the moment my experimental code runs OK if I use non zero values. The log shows the values are still correct at that point so I am assuming the problem is after the bulkTransfer.